What charm is required to use the Honedukes Passageway behind the one-eyed witch statue in Hogwarts?
I just found a Hidden Field Guide Page that says the following:

HONEDUKES PASSAGEWAY
Hidden behind the statue of a one-eyed witch is a secret passageway from Hogwarts to the cellar at Honedukes. It can only be accessed using a particular charm.


I've gone ahead and found this exact one-eyed witch statue:

I've tried all the charms that I've unlocked so far, but I'm not able to open it or go through.
How can I use this passageway? What's the required charm for it?

It is part of a side quest given by Garreth Weasley: Dissending for Sweets.
As part of this quest, Garreth mentions that you can use the spell 'Dissendium' to open the secret passage to the Honeydukes basement through the one-eyed witch's passage. Because it is only used in this quest, the spell to open the passage is really only used as an interaction with the statue, not as an actual castable spell. You can find information on starting the quest here.

Ah. So there's no way to use the passageway until I've completed that quest?

You need to start this quest to learn about the charm, as you use the one-eyed witch's path in the course of the quest.

Here's the solution, don't know if it's considered a spoiler:

Once you’ve found the one-eyed witch, you’ll need to use Reparo to fix a broken elevator and descend further into the secret area. The next obstacle players will encounter is a steep rock wall that players cannot reach. Cast Levioso on a nearby platform and use the floating floorboard to parkour up the ledge.

From this guide.

The broken elevator and the rock wall are found after you get past the statue. When you talk to Garreth at the start of the quest, he gives you the spell to use.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas oh didn't know that, I'll leave the answer anyway, it's still related
